# Laravel app on Azure: Access denied for user 'azure'@'localhost'

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, azure

I am deploying a Laravel app to Azure (Web App + Mysql), so far I did the following steps :

1- Activated Mysql In App

2- Connected to BitBucket repository and made sure code was synced

3- Created .env file and set database variables as follows

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=port form Mysql connection string
DB_DATABASE=localdb
DB_USERNAME=azure
DB_PASSWORD=password form Mysql connection string
```

4- Ran `php artisan config:cache`

**The Problem :**

Running `php artisan migrate` returns this error :

```
  SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'azure'@'localhost' (using pa  

  ssword: YES) (SQL: select * from information_schema.tables where table_sche  

  ma = localdb and table_name = migrations and table_type = 'BASE TABLE')
```

Strange thing is,I ran `SHOW GRANTS FOR CURRENT_USER` In PhpMyadmin and it returned : 
`GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'azure'@'localhost'`

P.s : I got DB credentials from Kudu Debug Console and made sure there are no spaces before/after password or username

Comment: Did you try to change the ```DB_HOST=127.0.0.1``` to ```DB_HOST=localhost```?

Answer (score 6):

This is a problem in Laravel version 7.9.* with the variable DB_PASSWORD in your .env file.
If your password contains "#" Laravel will comment on every character after this symbol. For example, if your password is DB_PASSWORD = 85SF#G52a@ Laravel interprets it as DB_PASSWORD = 85SF ignoring the rest of the characters.

SOLUTION
Wrap the value of the DB_PASSWORD variable in double quotes like this:

```
DB_PASSWORD="85SF#G52a@"
```

It took me 2 days to found out the problem, I hope this could be helpful for someone who encounters the same problem.

Comment: it's 14 Feb 2023 and this is the best valentine gift I have ever received

Answer (score 0):

change it from

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=port form Mysql connection string
DB_DATABASE=localdb
DB_USERNAME=azure
DB_PASSWORD=password form Mysql connection string
```

to

```
DB_HOST=localhost
```

and test again

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I did and cleared config cache.. still the same issue

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same problem and while searching online, I came across your question. You can connect to the database using the user root instead of azure. The password for the user root is 'password'. If you still want to grant all privileges to the user azure, you can do that using the credentials for the user root.