# #1045 - Access denied for user 'azure'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

Tags: php, mysql, azure-devops, phpmyadmin, azure-web-app-service

I am using the Azure Web App service for my PHP app.

In my PHPMyAdmin dashboard when I run the following query I get the error :

my query:

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'poc-qa-team'@'%';
```

Error :

```
#1045 - Access denied for user 'azure'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

Any idea how to get this done.

Furthermore,

```
ON URL:  https://xyz-dev.azurewebsites.xyz/installer/ 

    Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function apache_get_version() in 

D:\home\site\wwwroot\installer\index.php:43 Stack trace: #0 

D:\home\site\wwwroot\installer\index.php(232): checkDependencies() #1 {main} thrown in 

D:\home\site\wwwroot\installer\index.php on line 43
```

Note: Same app runs well in Azure VM LAMP stack

Comment: how are you trying to run the query? the error is not directly related to the query but may be related to the fact that the user can connect only to localhost and not to any remote hosts

Comment: You granted privileges to `poc-qa-team` but the application is connecting with `azure` as the username 

Comment: so does the azure web service permits us to run this query or how to grant permission from azure or this query can't run on the PHPMyAdmin dashboard which is running on the azure web service?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After searching this issue with key words `Access denied for user 'azure'@'localhost' (using password: YES)`.

The cause of the problem should still be the user name and password in the connection string. I concluded that you can try to solve the problem in the following ways.

***1. Create .env file.***

[Laravel app on Azure: Access denied for user 'azure'@'localhost'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61541607/laravel-app-on-azure-access-denied-for-user-azurelocalhost).

***2. Try to modify connection strings, `User` value should be `username` @ `hostname` .***

[mysqli_real_connect(): (HY000/1045): Access denied for user 'azure'@'localhost' (using password: YES)](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/azure/en-US/0c07f11d-970b-4ae7-b11b-57fef218dce0/mysqlirealconnect-hy0001045-access-denied-for-user-azurelocalhost-using-password?forum=AzureDatabaseforMySQL)